# Issue with custom UIActionSheet

Tags: ios, uiactionsheet

I am using an custom open-source action sheet that looks like this:

My problem is that when I import the header file to my project `DoActionSheet.h` the code breaks, So I add in all of the "Demo" files and the code works fine only when I use the same segmented control that is being used in the demo to pick and choose styles, for example:

```
DoActionSheet *vActionSheet = [[DoActionSheet alloc] init];
    vActionSheet.nAnimationType = _sgType.selectedSegmentIndex;

    if (_sgStyle.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
        [vActionSheet setStyle1];
    else if (_sgStyle.selectedSegmentIndex == 1)
        [vActionSheet setStyle2];
    else if (_sgStyle.selectedSegmentIndex == 2)
        [vActionSheet setStyle3];
```

But the moment that I remove the segmented control, say I choose `setStyle1` and do:

```
DoActionSheet *vActionSheet = [[DoActionSheet alloc] init];
        vActionSheet.nAnimationType = [vActionSheet setStyle1];
```

What am I doing wrong here? Is there a better way to go around this? I integrate a regular iOS `UIActionSheet` just fine, I just would like the look of this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% what you're trying to do, but this code doesn't set `nAnimationType` to an integer to change it's animation. It's simply calling the `setStyle1` method which returns `void` You're confusing the animation values with the methods for setting the appearance of the action sheet.

```
DoActionSheet *vActionSheet = [[DoActionSheet alloc] init];
vActionSheet.nAnimationType = [vActionSheet setStyle1];
```

You probably want something like this:

```
DoActionSheet *vActionSheet = [[DoActionSheet alloc] init];
vActionSheet.nAnimationType = 0;   // to use the normal animation or 1
vActionSheet.nAnimationType = 1;   // to fade it in
vActionSheet.nAnimationType = 2;   // 2 to bounce/pop it in
```

If you want to change the appearance of the alert view's buttons, background etc... call one of these methods on the action sheet instance:

```
[vActionSheet setStyle1];
[vActionSheet setStyle2];
[vActionSheet setStyle3];
```

Finally, the demo project doesn't produce a static library or a framework, so it looks to me like you need all the source code if you're going to use this class and its extensions in your project. It shouldn't be hard to integrate the bits you need.

All you should need to do is create a new Group in Xcode called "DoActionSheet", then drag/drop (from Finder) the 3rd Party Source and DoActionSheet folders from the demo project's folder right into the new group you just created. Then you would the header files just as they're done in the demo's ViewController.m. Use that as a guide for using the DoActionSheet class.

Comment: that is the strangest part for me, I tried doing what you told me to do in your last paragraph. I import the header file, and when I place my conjuration for different properties that are declared in the header file (which has already been imported to my VC) they come up with a red alert that states "property not found on object type myMainConroller" any clues?

Comment: So, even with the header imported in my viewController class It still won't recognize the properties I am trying to access... I am confused about this

Comment: Are the .h and .m files actually in your project or are they just linked to the directory of the sample app. Basically, in order to get this to work you need to get all the necessary source files (see the last paragraph in my answer) into your project. Those files need to also be a part of your members of your application's target

Comment: they have been added as you said let me try deleting them and trying again

Comment: I am still stuck.... take a look at the details I added here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25336186/unable-to-access-properties-in-other-classes-that-have-been-imported-to-viewcont